# How do I read half precision floating point numbers from a Metal texture with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, metal

My Metal compute kernel writes to a texture with format MTLPixelFormat.RG16Float, half precision floating point numbers. This is because Metal does not support writing to 32 bits floating point textures.

I need to read these half precision numbers in my swift program? I have moved the texture into a Swift UInt8 array, but I cannot figure out how to convert the half precision floats into Swift floats.

Comment: Say, what is a "Metal compute kernel" ?  URL??  cheers!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MetalShadingLanguageGuide/func-var-qual/func-var-qual.html

Comment: @Hallgrim, related question: I also found that 32-bit floats aren't writable with Metal kernels (generates assertion failure), however the docs seem to indicate they should be; See table here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MetalConstants_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MTLPixelFormat
Did you find any other official information on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: the below answer was written for Swift v1. Later versions of Swift added support via the float16_t type. Manual conversion may still be useful in some cases.

---

There is no built in method to interpret halfs as floats, you have to convert it yourself.
The half datatype is a floating point format following IEEE 754. You can read the values in your swift program using UInt16 and then convert from this to a float value.
I don't know of any conversion routines written in Swift, but here are two libraries written in C++ that could be converted easily enough:

http://mrob.com/pub/math/s10e5.h.txt

http://half.sourceforge.net/

In the first library it is the function operator float() that you need to convert, that takes the UInt16 member variable _h and outputs a float.

Answer (score 3):

Actually @Muzza's answer is not correct. You could have read them from a `float16_t` pointer and cast them to a normal `float32_t`. No need to use external libraries. Just import the `arm_neon` header.